# Error Code: 1248 Alias needed in MySQL

Tags: mysql, table

I have recently started learning MySQL and am trying to join data from two tables into a third table built.

The two tables are:

'Company Financials'   -   Column of 'Revenue'

'Fortune500'   -    Columns of 'Year' and 'Company'

My query code is:

`INSERT INTO Company(ID, Year, Company, Revenue)
    (select Year, Company, Revenue
    from (select Revenue from Company_Financials
    union select Year, Company from Fortune500));`

Fortune 500 Table:

[image: Fortune500 Table]

Company Financials Table:

[image: Company Financials table]

I've had multiple errors related to this code, but have been able to figure out why they were wrong.  This one is stumping me :(

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Each derived table needs alias asigned: `INSERT INTO Company(ID, Year, Company, Revenue)
    (select Year, Company, Revenue
    from (select Revenue from Company_Financials
    union select Year, Company from Fortune500) AS tempTable);`

Comment: @jkavalik I tried the code using the 'as temp' statement, but now it says, "Error Code: 1146. Table 'fortune_500.company_financials' doesn't exist". Since I was new to mySQL I built the tables using the schemas tab on the left side.  Do I need to build them through query?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You want a JOIN and not UNION in your case. The tables do not have the same columns so they cannot be unioned. And this error means you are using wrong active database or wrong table name.

Comment: Also, the way you have it, you are putting`Revenue` into `ID`.  If `ID` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, leave it out of the `INSERT` list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JOIN` by `ID` instead of the `UNION`.
Using `JOIN` there is no need of the sub-query.
Also `(` before `SELECT` is not required after the `INSERT INTO`.

So the working query is:

```
INSERT INTO Company (Year, Company, Revenue) 
SELECT FR.Year, FR.Company, CF.Revenue
FROM Fortune500 FR
JOIN Comp_Financials CF ON CF.ID = FR.ID;
```

Added [More explanation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/144044/83113) in this post, why you need to avoid `UNION`, and use `JOIN` for your requirement.

Comment: @AnthonyPotts: If this answer solves your problem, you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043). So it informs others that your issue is resolved.