# Error code 1054: Unknown column when inserting data into a table

Tags: mysql, insert, table

I have been trying to join data from two separate tables with distinct columns into a third table, but

> Error code 1054: Unknown Column 'Company' in field list

keeps popping up.

My current code is:

```
INSERT INTO Company (Year, Company, Revenue, Profits) 
(select Year, Company, Revenue, Profits from 
(select Year, Comp_Name from Comp_Info
union
select Revenue, Profits from Comp_Financials) 
AS tempTable);
```

Comp_Financials table:

[image: Comp_Financials]

Comp_Info table:

[image: Comp_Info Table]

Both tables will be combined into the already created table:
Company (ID int auto_increment, Year int, Company varchar (20), Revenue int, Profits int, Primary key (ID))

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is awfully similar to your previous, answered, question: [Error Code: 1248 Alias needed in MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143528/error-code-1248-alias-needed-in-mysql)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It is, but since I am new to MySQL i built the tables in the schema section instead of using query. I changed a few things but got stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN` by `ID` instead of the `UNION`.
Using `JOIN` there is no need of the sub-query.
Also `(` before SELECT is not required after the `INSERT INTO`.

So the working query is:

```
INSERT INTO Company (Year, Company, Revenue, Profits) 
SELECT CI.Year, CI.Comp_Name AS Company, CF.Revenue, CF.Profits
FROM Comp_Info AS CI
JOIN Comp_Financials AS CF ON CF.ID = CI.ID;
```

---

**More explanation**:

What you have tried with `UNION` is the wrong approach. Let me explain with a small example.

I'm creating the `Comp_Info` and `Comp_Financials` are the temporary table for the example

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Comp_Info (Id INT, Year INT, Comp_Name VARCHAR (200));

INSERT INTO Comp_Info (Id, Year, Comp_Name) VALUES
(1, 2005, 'Wal-Mart'), (2, 2005, 'Exxon Mobil'), (3, 2005, 'General Motors');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Comp_Financials (Id INT, Revenue INT, Profits INT);

INSERT INTO Comp_Financials (Id, Revenue, Profits) VALUES
(1, 288189, 10267), (2, 270772, 25330), (3, 193517, 2805);
```

Using the sample data the `UNION` will result as:

```
SELECT Year, Comp_Name FROM Comp_Info
UNION
SELECT Revenue, Profits FROM Comp_Financials;

|Year      | Comp_Name       |
|----------|---------------- |
|2005      | Wal-Mart        |
|2005      | Exxon Mobil     |
|2005      | General Motors  |
|288189    | 10267           |
|270772    | 25330           |
|193517    | 2805            |
```

But with the same sample data, the `JOIN` will result as:

```
SELECT CI.Year, CI.Comp_Name AS Company, CF.Revenue, CF.Profits
FROM Comp_Info AS CI
JOIN Comp_Financials AS CF ON CF.ID = CI.ID;

| Year  | Company           | Revenue   | Profits   
|------ |------------------ |---------- |---------
| 2005  | Wal-Mart          | 288189    | 10267
| 2005  | Exxon Mobil       | 270772    | 25330
| 2005  | General Motors    | 193517    | 2805
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That explanation was awesome and  it works perfectly!  When you type out the code `FROM Comp_Info CI
JOIN Comp_Financials CF` does that define Comp_Info as CI in the code?

Comment: @AnthonyPotts Yes. The `Comp_Info CI` and `Comp_Financials CF` are same as `Comp_Info AS CI` and `Comp_Financials AS CF`. The alias name can be used with/without `AS`. Anyway updated the same in the answer.